# Choose Destination folder for Free File

Tags: excel, vba, file

The script below is incomplete because I would like the destination file to be opened from a folder that the user has previously chosen. The file name is set but the user can choose which folder the file should reside in.

Essentially, the objective of this script is to create a pipe delimited file from an excel sheet residing in this file. Subsequently the user chooses the folder to save down the text file into a folder.

```
Sub PipeDelimited()

    ' Exports to PipeDel.txt file
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CurrRow As Range
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Dim CurrTextStr As String
    Dim ListSep As String
    Dim DestFile As String

    ListSep = "|"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("jj")
    Set Rng = Worksheets("jj").UsedRange

    DestFile ====> use msoFileDialogFolderPicker??????
    File name is set under Cell d8 in the tab (sheet) called macros

    Open DestFile For Output As #1

    For Each CurrRow In Rng.Rows
        CurrTextStr = ""

        For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
            CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & CurrCell.Value & ListSep
        Next

        While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
            CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
        Wend

        'Added next line to put | at end of each line
        CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & ListSep
        Print #1, CurrTextStr
    Next
    Close #1
End Sub
```

I have now added this sub with the intention that the vba script will automatically place a suffix of txt to my file.

The sub below does default my file type to txt. However, when I click on ok, nothing happens. The pop up window "please choose folder location to save this file" pops up each time I click on "ok". However, the file doesn't get saved.

```
Sub FolderLocation()

Dim folderpath As String
Dim fn As String
Dim fd As FileDialog

fn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACROS").Range("RngFileName").Value

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.Title = "Please Choose Folder Location to Save this File"
fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macros").Range("RngFileName").Value
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
fd.Filters.Add "Text", "*.txt", 1
fd.FilterIndex = 1
If fd.Show = True Then folderpath = fd.SelectedItems(1)


MsgBox "File Saved", vbOKCancel, folderpath

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the errors, what is the expected output and what do you really get?

Answer (score 2):

Adapt this basic outline for your code.  You will need to concatenate your filename to the `selectedFolder` path.

```
Sub getFolder()
Dim newFldrDia As FileDialog
Dim selectedFolder As String

Set newFldrDia = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With newFldrDia
        .Title = "My Dialog Title"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                selectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
    End With

MsgBox selectedFolder

End Sub
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863983(v=office.15).aspx) for more properties/methods you can use.